# raspberry pi pico temperature reading and output to zabbix

Tags: pi-pico

there is a raspberry pi pico that I want to configure as a temperature sensor, and output data to zabbix

raspberry pi pico I have, connected to a computer with ubuntu 22.04 via usb, I have a code for reading the temperature, which I run in thonny and get the temperature, but the problem is that this temperature is output either to the thonny terminal or to .txt in the pico file system.

I could not find information on how to write a file.the txt file with the temperature directly to the computer or any other ways to output from raspbery Pi from pico to Zabbix

code for getting the temperature:

```
import machine
import time
 
sensor_temp = machine.ADC(4)
conversion_factor = 3.3 / (65535)

temp = ()

while True:
    reading = sensor_temp.read_u16() * conversion_factor 
    temperature = 27 - (reading - 0.706)/0.001721
#    print(f'Температура: {temperature}°C')
    temp = temperature
    print(temp)
    time.sleep(1)
```

thank you very much!

Comment: Do not use Thonny. You will need a program to communicate with the Pico (serial over USB would seem to be easiest) which does the logging.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this by using a Pi Pico W and connecting to the wireless. I am using a DHT11 for temperature and 2 x INA219 to read dual voltages. One for batteries and one for site power. I have it setup to respond to a web browser with a page that displays the values. I then setup Zabbix to pull the HTML and then parse the values using JavaScript and save as a floating number so that I can look at it on a graph and write alerts.

I eventually would like to connect an Ethernet hat to a regular Pi Pico so that I do not need to worry about the wireless. Maybe even add SNMP support for polling but alas there is no time.

If you are still interested let me know and I can post some details.